# NSFilePromiseReceiver returns NSURLErrorDomain -1001 "(null)" when receiving files

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I've been working to update the `performDragOperation` method to use `NSFilePromiseReceiver`. However, any time I drag a file, the reader returns

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "(null)"

Here's the code:

```
NSString *tempPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempPath isDirectory:true];
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
NSArray *filePromises = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:@[[NSFilePromiseReceiver class]] options:@{}];

// promised files have to be created in a specific directory
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:tempPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil] == false)
{
  return false;
}

if (filePromises.count > 0)
{
  for (NSFilePromiseReceiver *fileReceiver in filePromises) {
    [fileReceiver receivePromisedFilesAtDestination:tempURL options:@{} operationQueue:[NSOperationQueue new] reader:^(NSURL * _Nonnull fileURL, NSError * _Nullable errorOrNil) {
      if (errorOrNil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorOrNil);
        NSLog(@"URL: %@", tempURL);
        return;
      }

      NSLog(@"fileURL: %@", fileURL);
    }];
  }

  return YES;
}
else
{
  return NO;
}
```

I can see that the directory is created and the file is generated, but `errorOrNil` always returns the above error.

Comment: Don't use paths, use urls. `NSTemporaryDirectory`: "See the NSFileManager method URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error: for the preferred means of finding the correct temporary directory.".

Comment: from what app to you start the drag?

Comment: I get the same error when dragging from Apple Mail. Was that your source? The weird thing is the .eml file is written to disk, but the file promise fails. The reader block doesn't have the URL to the file in it.